# Recurssive DB2 Sql query to be used in informatica Source Qualifier Transformation

Tags: sql, db2

i need to calculate metric values for 50 columns with same calculation  pattern. i cannot use Union Query for all 50 columns as Source Qualifier        in Informatica designer can hold upto 32767 characters.can anyone        suggest ways TO achieve this ?

```
    SELECT djm.jobcode|| '_' || djm.job_region || '_' || 
      md.srvy_country_cd || '_' || djm.match_year AS srvy_label, 
           djm.match_year, 
           'NA'            AS SRVY_PUBLISHER, 
           'Blend'         AS cut, 
           'MI_UNIV_BLEND' AS srvy_name, 
           md.srvy_country_cd, 
     ( md.base_25 ) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff ) AS adj_base_25, 
( md.base_50 ) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff )    adj_base_50, 
( md.base_75 ) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff ) AS adj_base_75, 
           NULL  AS adj_COMM_25, 
           NULL   AS adj_COMM_50, 
           NULL AS adj_COMM_75, 
           djm.weight, 
           Sum(djm.weight) OVER (partition BY 
djm.jobcode,djm.job_region,djm.match_year) sum_weight, 
           djm.weight*100 / Sum(djm.weight) OVER (partition BY 
djm.jobcode,djm.job_region,djm.match_year) adj_weight 
FROM       md 
INNER JOIN djm 
ON         djm.sk = md.sk 
AND        djm.jobcode ='1234' 
AND        djm.job_region ='USAB' 
AND        djm.match_year ='2016' 
AND        ( ( Nvl(md.base_25, 0) > 0 AND Nvl(md.base_50, 0) > 0 
            AND Nvl(md.base_75, 0) > 0 ) ) 
UNION 
SELECT djm.jobcode|| '_' || djm.job_region || '_' || md.srvy_country_cd || 
'_' || djm.match_year AS srvy_label,  
           djm.match_year, 
           'NA'            AS SRVY_PUBLISHER, 
           'Blend'         AS cut, 
           'MI_UNIV_BLEND' AS srvy_name, 
           md.srvy_country_cd, 
           NULL AS adj_base_25, 
           NULL AS adj_base_50, 
           NULL  AS adj_base_75, 
 ( md.comm_25) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff ) AS adj_COMM_25, 
 ( md.comm_50) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff ) AS adj_COMM_50, 
 ( md.comm_75) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff ) AS adj_COMM_75, 
           djm.weight, 
           Sum(djm.weight) OVER (partition BY 
 djm.jobcode,djm.job_region,djm.match_year)sum_weight, 
           djm.weight*100 / Sum(djm.weight) OVER (partition BY 
djm.jobcode,djm.job_region,djm.match_year) adj_weight 
FROM       md 
INNER JOIN djm 
ON         djm.sk = md.sk 
AND        djm.jobcode ='12178' 
AND        djm.job_region ='USAB' 
AND        djm.match_year ='2016' 
AND        ( (  Nvl(md.comm_25, 0) > 0 AND Nvl(md.comm_50, 0) > 0 
            AND Nvl(md.comm_75, 0) > 0 ) )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do you think anyone would help you with a such bad formatted question? Please take a few minutes to format it correctly...

Comment: hi @DaFois the query was autoformatted now i have corrected the code. could you please provide your feedback/suggestion.

Comment: @udayadevan . . . Use views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need 50 columns or 50 rows. This will give you 50 rows (I guess) if you put all 50 rows in the `VALUES` sub-select. (You could also use a table there)

```
SELECT djm.jobcode|| '_' || djm.job_region || '_' ||  md.srvy_country_cd || '_' || djm.match_year AS srvy_label, 
           djm.match_year, 
           'NA'            AS SRVY_PUBLISHER, 
           'Blend'         AS cut, 
           'MI_UNIV_BLEND' AS srvy_name, 
           md.srvy_country_cd, 
     ( md.base_25 ) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff ) AS adj_base_25, 
( md.base_50 ) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff )    adj_base_50, 
( md.base_75 ) * ( 1 + djm.adjustment ) * ( djm.geo_diff ) AS adj_base_75, 
           NULL  AS adj_COMM_25, 
           NULL   AS adj_COMM_50, 
           NULL AS adj_COMM_75, 
           djm.weight, 
           Sum(djm.weight) OVER (partition BY djm.jobcode,djm.job_region,djm.match_year) sum_weight, 
           djm.weight*100 / Sum(djm.weight) OVER (partition BY djm.jobcode,djm.job_region,djm.match_year) adj_weight 
FROM       md 
INNER JOIN djm 
ON         djm.sk = md.sk 

AND        ( ( Nvl(md.base_25, 0) > 0 AND Nvl(md.base_50, 0) > 0 
            AND Nvl(md.base_75, 0) > 0 ) ) 
INNER JOIN
TABLE( VALUES (  '1234', 'USAB', '2016')
,       ( '12178', 'USAB', '2016')
-- etc etc
) 
AS s(jobcode,job_region,match_year)
ON         djm.jobcode = s.jobcode
AND        djm.job_region = s.job_region
AND        djm.match_year = s.match_year
```

If you do need 50 columns, you can always pivot them out with e.g. a SUM(CASE WHEN...)` for each column over the result set below